# Why does this spreadsheet overflow to the other page?

Tags: lyx

I am using LYX version 2.3.2. I have a spreadsheet which has 13 columns, one with names and the
other with monthly values. I import the spreadhsheet into a float using the normal Insert-> File -> external material. When I convert the lyx into a PDF, the outcome appears as below, with the columns falling off the page:
[image: You can clearly see 'January' about to begin]

Some examples of things I have tried: formatting the spreadsheet which I import, for example changing the headers and shrinking the columns; setting the scaling of the spreadsheet file to 1%, etc.

I would appreciate any help!

To respond to a comment, below is the code corresponding to the table in question.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{centering}
\def\inputGnumericTable{}\input{/home/abed/Google Drive/Utrecht Energy Science MSc/MSc Materials/Research Project/AnalysisData/torques_average_waves.tex}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{Torque imparted by ``average'' waves for a given month, in units
of $10^{5}Nm$}
\end{table}
```

To respond to one more question, this is what the contents of the file look like:

[image: the spreadsheet which is imported]

This is what the auto-generated .tex file looks like:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This is the header of a LaTeX2e file exported from Gnumeric.    %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This file can be compiled as it stands or included in another   %%
%%  LaTeX document. The table is based on the longtable package so  %%
%%  the longtable options (headers, footers...) can be set in the   %%
%%  preamble section below (see PRAMBLE).                           %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  To include the file in another, the following two lines must be %%
%%  in the including file:                                          %%
%%        \def\inputGnumericTable{}                                 %%
%%  at the beginning of the file and:                               %%
%%        \input{name-of-this-file.tex}                             %%
%%  where the table is to be placed. Note also that the including   %%
%%  file must use the following packages for the table to be        %%
%%  rendered correctly:                                             %%
%%    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                                 %%
%%    \usepackage{color}                                            %%
%%    \usepackage{array}                                            %%
%%    \usepackage{longtable}                                        %%
%%    \usepackage{calc}                                             %%
%%    \usepackage{multirow}                                         %%
%%    \usepackage{hhline}                                           %%
%%    \usepackage{ifthen}                                           %%
%%  optionally (for landscape tables embedded in another document): %%
%%    \usepackage{lscape}                                           %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%  This section checks if we are begin input into another file or  %%
%%  the file will be compiled alone. First use a macro taken from   %%
%%  the TeXbook ex 7.7 (suggestion of Han-Wen Nienhuys).            %%
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax}


%%  Check for the \def token for inputed files. If it is not        %%
%%  defined, the file will be processed as a standalone and the     %%
%%  preamble will be used.                                          %%
\ifundefined{inputGnumericTable}

%%  We must be able to close or not the document at the end.        %%
    \def\gnumericTableEnd{\end{document}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This is the PREAMBLE. Change these values to get the right      %%
%%  paper size and other niceties.                                  %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \documentclass[12pt%
              %,landscape%
                    ]{report}
       \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
       \usepackage{fullpage}
       \usepackage{color}
       \usepackage{array}
       \usepackage{longtable}
       \usepackage{calc}
       \usepackage{multirow}
       \usepackage{hhline}
       \usepackage{ifthen}

    \begin{document}


%%  End of the preamble for the standalone. The next section is for %%
%%  documents which are included into other LaTeX2e files.          %%
\else

%%  We are not a stand alone document. For a regular table, we will %%
%%  have no preamble and only define the closing to mean nothing.   %%
    \def\gnumericTableEnd{}

%%  If we want landscape mode in an embedded document, comment out  %%
%%  the line above and uncomment the two below. The table will      %%
%%  begin on a new page and run in landscape mode.                  %%
%       \def\gnumericTableEnd{\end{landscape}}
%       \begin{landscape}


%%  End of the else clause for this file being \input.              %%
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  The rest is the gnumeric table, except for the closing          %%
%%  statement. Changes below will alter the table's appearance.     %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\providecommand{\gnumericmathit}[1]{#1} 
%%  Uncomment the next line if you would like your numbers to be in %%
%%  italics if they are italizised in the gnumeric table.           %%
%\renewcommand{\gnumericmathit}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\providecommand{\gnumericPB}[1]%
{\let\gnumericTemp=\\#1\let\\=\gnumericTemp\hspace{0pt}}
 \ifundefined{gnumericTableWidthDefined}
        \newlength{\gnumericTableWidth}
        \newlength{\gnumericTableWidthComplete}
        \newlength{\gnumericMultiRowLength}
        \global\def\gnumericTableWidthDefined{}
 \fi
%% The following setting protects this code from babel shorthands.  %%
 \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\languageshorthands}}{}{\languageshorthands{english}}
%%  The default table format retains the relative column widths of  %%
%%  gnumeric. They can easily be changed to c, r or l. In that case %%
%%  you may want to comment out the next line and uncomment the one %%
%%  thereafter                                                      %%
\providecommand\gnumbox{\makebox[0pt]}
%%\providecommand\gnumbox[1][]{\makebox}

%% to adjust positions in multirow situations                       %%
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{\jot}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{\doublerulesep}

%%  The \setlongtables command keeps column widths the same across  %%
%%  pages. Simply comment out next line for varying column widths.  %%
\setlongtables

\setlength\gnumericTableWidth{%
    37pt+%
    42pt+%
    34pt+%
    34pt+%
    32pt+%
    37pt+%
    33pt+%
    35pt+%
    32pt+%
    31pt+%
    30pt+%
    30pt+%
    30pt+%
0pt}
\def\gumericNumCols{13}
\setlength\gnumericTableWidthComplete{\gnumericTableWidth+%
         \tabcolsep*\gumericNumCols*2+\arrayrulewidth*\gumericNumCols}
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\gnumericTableWidthComplete > \linewidth}}%
         {\def\gnumericScale{\ratio{\linewidth-%
                        \tabcolsep*\gumericNumCols*2-%
                        \arrayrulewidth*\gumericNumCols}%
{\gnumericTableWidth}}}%
{\def\gnumericScale{1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%% The following are the widths of the various columns. We are      %%
%% defining them here because then they are easier to change.       %%
%% Depending on the cell formats we may use them more than once.    %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColA}}{\newlength{\gnumericColA}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColA}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{37pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColB}}{\newlength{\gnumericColB}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColB}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{42pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColC}}{\newlength{\gnumericColC}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColC}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{34pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColD}}{\newlength{\gnumericColD}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColD}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{34pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColE}}{\newlength{\gnumericColE}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColE}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{32pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColF}}{\newlength{\gnumericColF}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColF}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{37pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColG}}{\newlength{\gnumericColG}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColG}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{33pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColH}}{\newlength{\gnumericColH}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColH}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{35pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColI}}{\newlength{\gnumericColI}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColI}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{32pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColJ}}{\newlength{\gnumericColJ}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColJ}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{31pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColK}}{\newlength{\gnumericColK}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColK}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{30pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColL}}{\newlength{\gnumericColL}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColL}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{30pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColM}}{\newlength{\gnumericColM}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColM}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{30pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}

\begin{longtable}[c]{%
    b{\gnumericColA}%
    b{\gnumericColB}%
    b{\gnumericColC}%
    b{\gnumericColD}%
    b{\gnumericColE}%
    b{\gnumericColF}%
    b{\gnumericColG}%
    b{\gnumericColH}%
    b{\gnumericColI}%
    b{\gnumericColJ}%
    b{\gnumericColK}%
    b{\gnumericColL}%
    b{\gnumericColM}%
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  The longtable options. (Caption, headers... see Goosens, p.124) %%
%   \caption{The Table Caption.}             \\ %
% \hline    % Across the top of the table.
%%  The rest of these options are table rows which are placed on    %%
%%  the first, last or every page. Use \multicolumn if you want.    %%

%%  Header for the first page.                                      %%
%   \multicolumn{13}{c}{The First Header} \\ \hline 
%   \multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag}  %Column 1
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 2
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 3
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 4
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 5
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 6
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 7
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 8
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 9
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 10
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 11
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 12
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} \\ \hline %Last column
%   \endfirsthead

%%  The running header definition.                                  %%
%   \hline
%   \multicolumn{13}{l}{\ldots\small\slshape continued} \\ \hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag}  %Column 1
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 2
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 3
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 4
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 5
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 6
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 7
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 8
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 9
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 10
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 11
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 12
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} \\ \hline %Last column
%   \endhead

%%  The running footer definition.                                  %%
%   \hline
%   \multicolumn{13}{r}{\small\slshape continued\ldots} \\
%   \endfoot

%%  The ending footer definition.                                   %%
%   \multicolumn{13}{c}{That's all folks} \\ \hline 
%   \endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     \gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Name}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Jan}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Feb}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Mar}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Apr}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{May}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Jun}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Jul}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Aug}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Sep}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Oct}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Nov}}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{\textbf{Dec }}
\\
     \gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{Port Shepstone}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.66283}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.523}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.535}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.82}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.5479}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.535}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.738}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.427}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.534}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.633}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.231}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.71}
\\
     \gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{Puerto Colombia}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{3.14227}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{3.622}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{2.734}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.219}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.1477}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.143}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.354}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.086}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.001}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.001}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.153}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.51}
\\
     \gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{Port of Rotterdam}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.81305}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.975}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.354}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.089}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.0613}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.032}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.027}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.045}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.195}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.77}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.995}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{1.45}
\\
     \gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{South Golden Beach}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.25007}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.24}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.283}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.22}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.2363}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.279}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.345}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.279}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.303}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.387}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.328}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.311}
\\
     \gnumericPB{\raggedright}\gnumbox[l]{Katsuura}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.94642}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.882}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.803}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.427}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.184}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.052}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.043}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.012}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.134}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.311}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.363}
    &\gnumericPB{\raggedleft}\gnumbox[r]{0.68}
\\
\end{longtable}

\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\languageshorthands}}{}{\languageshorthands{\languagename}}
\gnumericTableEnd
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please show the latex code that corresponds to the screenshot, preferrably in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thank you, I have done this.

Comment: How do the contents of the file `AnalysisData/torques_average_waves.tex` look like?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the spreadsheet which is imported. I do not add the .tex file directly, instead the spreadsheet which is a .xls.

Comment: Please add the contents of the file directly into your question. The `.tex` file I mentioned in my previous comment contains the latex code that is used to procude the table in your document. It seems to have been auto-generated in some way. In order to tell you why your table does not fit into your page, we need to see the code of the actual table, hence my question for the contents of `torques_average_waves.tex`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help and patience. I have added the contents of that file. It's quite large actually!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is more of a "workaround," but, what I did is: I found the spreadsheet which I used for another table where the conversion seemed to have worked. I copied and pasted the format of the working spreadsheet into the one which wasn't working, and that fixed it. The column widths look fine. I could not find where the problem was in the .tex files however; my guess is that's something not obvious, like perhaps the row heights? That changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Lyx nor tables generated by Gnumeric. I also don't really understand why one would use an auto-generated code if a simple `tabular` such as the following works perfectly fine:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{l}}
     \textbf{Name}      &\textbf{Jan} &\textbf{Feb} &\textbf{Mar} &\textbf{Apr} &\textbf{May} &\textbf{Jun}
                        &\textbf{Jul} &\textbf{Aug} &\textbf{Sep} &\textbf{Oct} &\textbf{Nov} &\textbf{Dec} \\
     Puerto Colombia    & 3.14227     & 3.622       & 2.734       & 1.219       & 0.1477      & 0.143 
                        & 0.354       & 0.086       & 0.001       & 0.001       & 0.153       & 1.51        \\
     Port of Rotterdam  & 1.81305     & 0.975       & 0.354       & 0.089       & 0.0613      & 0.032
                        & 0.027       & 0.045       & 0.195       & 0.77        & 0.995       & 1.45        \\
     South Golden Beach & 0.25007     & 0.24        & 0.283       & 0.22        & 0.2363      & 0.279 
                        & 0.345       & 0.279       & 0.303       & 0.387       & 0.328       & 0.311       \\
     Katsuura           & 0.94642     & 0.882       & 0.803       & 0.427       & 0.184       & 0.052 
                        & 0.043       & 0.012       & 0.134       & 0.311       & 0.363       & 0.68
  \end{tabular}
```